# Best Way To Disable Button In Form When Required Fields Are Not Entered

Tags: jquery

The code below disables the submit button of form if all required fields are not filled out. Problem is if it is filled out then afterwards erased the button stays enabled. How do I fix that?

```
$(".submit").prop('disabled', true);
$('.required').keyup(function () {
    if ($(".fname").val() != "" && $(".lname").val() != "" && $(".userName").val() != "" && $(".familyRav").val() != "" && $(".birthday").val() != "" && $(".password").val() != '' && $(".confirm_password").val() != '' && $(".password").val() ===  $(".confirm_password").val()) {
        $(".submit").prop("disabled", false);

    }
});
```

Comment: Just hide it than disabling it

Comment: `else $(".submit").prop("disabled", true);`?

Comment: Make a variable, `isValid`, that is equal to your `if` condition and set the disabled property to `!isValid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your if to an if/else:

```
if ($(".fname").val() != "" && $(".lname").val() != "" && $(".userName").val() != "" && $(".familyRav").val() != "" && $(".birthday").val() != "" && $(".password").val() != '' && $(".confirm_password").val() != '' && $(".password").val() ===  $(".confirm_password").val()) {
    $(".submit").prop("disabled", false);
} else $(".submit").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **CSS only** solution with. Not always we should jump on the javascript solutions :)

```css
#frm1:invalid #btn1 {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: graytext;
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1">
  name: <input name="n1" type="text" required="required" /><br />
  phone: <input name="n2" type="text" required="required" /><br />
  mail: <input name="n3" type="text" required="required" /><br />
  check: <input name="n4" type="checkbox" required="required" /><br />
  radio: <input name="n5" type="radio" required="required" /><br />
  <input id="btn1" type="submit" value="click" />
</form>
```

> It's important to note that if someone will hit the `enter` inside the form - it will be sent (because there is not way to control the "disabled" attribute of the submit button from CSS). This solution is for styling only.

The click on the submit button was disabled using the `pointer-events`.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted by this new (for me) CSS selector. I will check how this can be usefull for me. But since you mentioned it can't prevent an [enter] that leads to submit... It ain't fullproof for the present case. It is indeed *very, very, very* interesting for checkboxes and radios. A keep in mind one! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Sure it owes an upvote... For my personnal knowledge, My mice just want to do it!. But for OP, I'm not sure. He clearly stated he want's a password repeat match. This can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to ensure ALL `.required` elements will be filled before the submit button can get enabled.

The function does not depends of a list of "specific" fields.
Only the `.required` class is enought.

So the HTML is easier to maintain.

```
$(".submit").prop('disabled', true);

$('.required').keyup(function () {

    // Each time a check is performed, consider the button disabled as a start.
    $(".submit").prop('disabled', true);


    // Set a var to use as a "flag".
    var requiredAllCompleted = true;

    // Cycle through them all.  
    $('.required').each(function(){
        if( ($this).val() == "" ){
            requiredAllCompleted = false;
        }
    });

    // If all required fields not empty
    if ( requiredAllCompleted){

        // Additional check for password match.
        if( $(".password").val() ===  $(".confirm_password").val()) {

            // Unlock the submit button.
            $(".submit").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe the keyup event is a bit overkill... `.on("change", function(){...` should be way enought... You to see.

Comment: Not getting enabled?

Comment: I suppose you tryed the above code AND also made the class changes in your HTML to add the class `.required` to all fields that is required. I assume that you undestood that classes `.password` and `.confirm_password` are still necessary. Okay? Are you sure that your button doesn't get enabled regarding this? If so, any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change the button to be disabled by default, as it makes no sense to disable the form for the first time only when the first thing is typed in a required field.

You should probably encapsulate this behavior into a function that can be called on different events.  For example, if your form is pre-populated, perhaps you want to run this check on page load to set initial button state in addition to calling this function during changes in data.

I consider would binding this to change event for the relevent form fields rather than keyup.  Key up might be valuable to bind against if you wanted to give individual field validation feedback while user is typing, but is it really meaningful to try to change the button enabled/disabled status for every key press?

I would echo thoughts of @LouysPatriceBessette that you should not need to hard-code field names here if you already have a class defined for the required fields that you can easily select against and iterate to validate the values are non empty strings.

Comment: Thanks for the "echo"... But, based on the provided code, I don't think OP is near "encapsulating" his validation function to make it scallable to all his forms site-wide. To give him the idea that it is possible isn't a bad thing thought. But this encapsed function would be more complex. It would certainly include many error messages depending on field "topic type", involving other knowledge like regular expressions.. Also, It would be good to mention that there is a couple "easy to use" validation plugins existing...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Agreed that best bet here would be to simply use one of the many good jQuery validation extensions.